# How does one plot $2^{x^{2}}$?

Tags: functions

I need to plot $2^{x^{2}}$ without using calculus. I would like to know how to explain why that function is smooth at $x=0.$

Comment: Do you want to plot on paper or a graphing calculator?  The former can be done by computing several points (in this case, around $x=0$).

Comment: Maybe you can argue that since both $2^x$ and $x^2$ are smooth at $x=0$ then so is the composition (that's the most "without using calculus" I get since smooth is a term in calculus ;))

Comment: @Argon: On a paper. But I failed to notice how it is "smooth".

Comment: you know that $x^2$ and $2^x$ are smooth and behave 'reasonably'. Why would their composition not? If you want a proof, not just intuition, then you'll need calculus, since that's where the definition of smooth comes from.

Comment: Why anyone would want to plot this without the tools of calculus is beyond me.But I guess it's a standard pre-calculus grind-it-out problem.One question I WOULD have for such a problem before answering is what does "smooth" mean in this particular problem-that derivatives of all orders exist and are continuous? I wouldn't think so given how the question is asked.

Comment: To save some work, notice that the function $2^{x^2}$ is even (ie. symmetric wrt the y-axis), so you only need to plot the graph for positive $x$ and the rest you get by mirroring that.